# An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback. in opencv code

Tags: python, opencv

so im runnin a code that extrack a frame for a video but somehow it show error "An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback." can u guys help me where im wrong?

```
import sys 
import argparse
import cv2

def extractImages(pathIn,pathOut):
count = 0
vidcap =cv2.VideoCapture(pathIn)
success,image= vidcap.read()
success = True
while success:
vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,(count*1000))
success,image =vidcap.read()
print('membaca frame baru: ',success)
cv2.imwrite( pathOut + "\\famr%d.jpg" %count ,image)
 count = count +1

if __name__=="__main__":
 a=argparse.ArgumentParser()
 a.add_argument("--pathIn",help="E:\test\test.mp4")
 a.add_argument("--pathOut",help="E:\test")
 args = a.parse_args()
 print(args)
 extractImages(args.pathIn , args.pathOut)
```

usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--pathIn PATHIN] [--pathOut PATHOUT]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\win 10\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-44699689-95ab-4b9a-9c79-7e6581b46e40.json

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

Comment: run that outside of a jupyter notebook and see if you get a useful error message. that one hints at jupyter being broken, but that is secondary. -- also be sure to format the python code so it's not syntactically broken (indentation is syntax, in python)

Comment: @Bang nelo.  Indentation isn't correct.